# linebreaking when using raisebox in section

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, titlesec

How to break the line when using `raisebox` command in `\section`. My MWE is :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,mdframed}

\definecolor{sectcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,.75,.39}
\definecolor{sectbgcolor}{RGB}{0,106,168}
\definecolor{sectsubbgcolor}{RGB}{0,139,191}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\section}
  {\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\color{white}\bfseries}
  {\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{2em}{\raggedleft%
      \colorbox{sectcolor}{%
        \makebox[\dimexpr2em-2\fboxsep\relax][r]{%
          \hfill\strut\thesection
        }%
      }\\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    }}\hspace*{0.5em}}%
  }
  {0em}
  {\makebox[\linewidth][l]{\colorbox{sectbgcolor}{\parbox[t]    {\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-2\fboxsep-5pt\relax}{%
    \strut\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\raisebox{-2.5pt}[0pt][0pt]{#1}%
    \if\sectionsubtitle\empty
    \else
      \hspace{5pt}\smash{\colorbox{sectsubbgcolor}    {\strut\large\sectionsubtitle}}%
    \fi}
    }}%
  }

\makeatother

\def\sectionsubtitle{\empty}
\newcommand\Ssection[3][]{%
  \gdef\sectionsubtitle{#3}\section[#1]{#2}\gdef\sectionsubtitle{\empty}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\section{Count systems}
\lipsum[1]
\Ssection{Number systems}{Consolidating}
\lipsum[1]
\Ssection{Highest common factor and lowest common\hfil\break     multiple}{Consolidating}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Remove the text `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]` from your code. This means that the code reads: `...\selectfont{#1}...` Why the `\raisebox` is here? What means "box" in the name `\rasebox`? That it is unbreakable compact element.

Comment: @wipet: Sorry. I have updated my questions. I would like to move the `section head` in top. How to move the `section head` without `raisebox` in this `section head`?

Comment: Using `\strut`s. Use `\vrule height15pt width0pt` instead `\strut` before `\fontsize`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should not be adding manual breaks to titles.  You should rather set-up your titling macro so that it spreads it over several lines as necessary.  In your case building a box to hold the background colour and putting a `parbox` inside to hold the text will accomplish this.

Secondly, I believe you are using a raisebox because the heights and depths are wrong.  This seems to be caused by using the wrong `\strut`.  Your coding `\strut\fontszie{...}\selectfont` means the strut is not adjusted to the new font size.  Instead write it in this order `\fontsize{...}\selectfont\strut.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\definecolor{sectcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,.75,.39}
\definecolor{sectbgcolor}{RGB}{0,106,168}
\definecolor{sectsubbgcolor}{RGB}{0,139,191}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\Alph{section}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{white}\fontsize{18}{20}\bfseries}
  {\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{2em}{\raggedleft%
      \colorbox{sectcolor}{%
        \makebox[\dimexpr2em-2\fboxsep\relax][r]{%
          \hfill\strut\thesection
        }%
      }\\[1ex]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    \includegraphics[width=1.5em]{image-1}\\[2pt]
    }}\hspace*{0.5em}}%
  }
  {0em}
  {\colorbox{sectbgcolor}{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-2\fboxsep-5pt\relax]{%
    {\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
      \raggedright\fontsize{18}{20}\selectfont\strut #1%
      \if\sectionsubtitle\empty
      \else
      \hspace{5pt}%
      \smash{\colorbox{sectsubbgcolor}{\large\strut\sectionsubtitle}}%
      \fi}}\hfill
      }}%
}

\def\sectionsubtitle{\empty}
\newcommand\Ssection[3][]{%
  \gdef\sectionsubtitle{#3}\section[#1]{#2}\gdef\sectionsubtitle{\empty}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Title Here}
\section{Count systems}
\lipsum[1]
\Ssection{Number systems}{Consolidating}
\lipsum[1]
\Ssection{Highest common factor and lowest common multiple}{Consolidating}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do indent the `section title` and `linebreaking` section title also?

Comment: You can add space before the `\parbox` if you wish.